# Give less weight to term frequency in solr?

Tags: solr, django-haystack

How do I change the scoring function of Solr to give less weight to "term frequency"?

I am using a pagerank-like document boost as a relevancy factor. My search index currently puts many documents that are "spammy" or not well-cleaned up and have repetitive words on top.

I know the score is calculated by term frequency (how often a search term is in the document), inverse document frequency, and others ([How are documents scored?](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_are_documents_scored)). I could just increase the boost, but that would disemphasize the other factors, too.

Is the way to go to specify a function at query time (and what is the default function), or do I have to change the configuration and reindex? I am using django-haystack with solr, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but this seems to work. I create a subclass of `Similarity` in java.  In `ClassicSimilarity`, term frequency is defined as `sqrt(freq)`. It doesn't make sense to add a multiplicative factor, since tf is multiplied with other terms, not added - the scale factor would just be uniformly applied. I.e. `scale * a * b` doesn't make sense, `scale * a + b` would. But what you can do in this case is `a^scale * b`. What this basically does is it applies a scale factor in the logarithm: `log(score) = scale * log(a) + log(b)`.

Also note that the default similarity function doesn't seem to be TF-IDF after all, but BM25. This here is a variation of TF-IDF.

```java
package com.example.solr;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity;

public class CustomSimilarity extends ClassicSimilarity {
    @Override
    public float tf(float freq) {
        return (float) Math.pow(freq, 0.25); // default: 0.5
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomSimularity";
    }
}
```

compile it with:

```
javac -cp /path/to/solr-6.6.1/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/lucene-core-6.6.1.jar:. -d . CustomSimilarity.java
jar -cvf myscorer.jar com
```

Then, add to `solrconfig.xml`:

```xml
<lib path="/path/to/myscorer.jar" />
```

and in `schema.xml`:

```xml
<similarity class="com.example.solr.CustomSimilarity">
</similarity>
```

After restarting solr, you can verify that the new similarity class is being used under `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/<corename>/schema`.

Comment: The default similarity switched to BM25 with the release of Solr6. You can also set the similarity class _per field_ now, so you can have one field with a different calculation than other fields.

Comment: Thanks for the information! For posteriority, here's an instructive link about the difference between TD-IDF and BM25 in Lucene: http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/